# Regexp find and replace with the found value

Tags: c#, regex

I have UK postcodes data and I would like to sort them alphabeticaly, when I do that the result is as follows;

```
N10-XX
N1-XX
N2-XX
N3-XX
N4-XX
N5-XX
```

What I want is that as follows;

```
N1-XX
N2-XX
N3-XX
N4-XX
N5-XX
N10-XX
```

Basicaly I need to add 0 at the begining of the number if it is 1 digit. like N1 should be N01 to be able to do that, what is the regexp pattern for that?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well if you are bent on using Regex, then this should do it

```
var text = @"N10-XX
N1-XX
N2-XX
N3-XX
N4-XX
N5-XX";

text = Regex.Replace(text, @"^N(\d)-", "N0$1-", RegexOptions.Multiline);
```

that said you obviously will be altering the original data, so I am not sure if this is even applicable

If you want to sort numerically, but preserve the original data, then you may need to do something like this

```
text.Split('\n')
    .Select(o => new { Original = o, Normal = Regex.Replace(o, @"^N(\d)-", "N0$1-", RegexOptions.Compiled)})
    .OrderBy(o => o.Normal)
    .Select(o => o.Original)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure from the example which numbers in the post code need to be ordered.  here is some regex examples for valid uk post codes http://blogs.creative-jar.com/post/Valid-UK-Postcdoe-formats.aspx.  if you incorporate this using the method above you should be able to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sort function returning original string in natural(?) order.

```
List<string> list1 = new List<string>{ "N10-XX","N1-XX","N2-XX","N3-XX","N4-XX","N5-XX" };
List<string> list2 = new List<string>() { "File (5).txt", "File (1).txt", "File (10).txt", "File (100).txt", "File (2).txt" };   

var sortedList1 = MySort(list1).ToArray();
var sortedList2 = MySort(list2).ToArray();


public static IEnumerable<string> MySort(IEnumerable<string> list)
{
    if (list.Count() == 0)
    {
        return new string[0];
    }

    int maxLen = list.Select(s => s.Length).Max();
    Func<string, char> PaddingChar = s => char.IsDigit(s[0]) ? ' ' : char.MaxValue;

    return 
        list.Select(s =>
                new
                {
                    OrgStr = s,
                    SortStr = Regex.Replace(s, @"(\d+)|(\D+)", m => m.Value.PadLeft(maxLen, PaddingChar(m.Value)))
                })
            .OrderBy(x => x.SortStr)
            .Select(x => x.OrgStr);
}
```